# How to have ctrl/cmd + b (build and run) in VSCode as in Sublime

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext3

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to "run and build" is convenient. What is the equivalent and most intuitive in VSCode? I used a tool `"Sublime Text Keymap and Settings Importer"` to get an easy transition to VSCode but build not included.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+B will run the build task.  Search for "build" in the gear icon/keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: If you don't describe what ctrl-b does we can't help you.

Comment: that is the default build and run command in sublime. thanks for the hint.